# Control to show a list view and a thumbnail/tile view

Tags: xaml, windows-8, wpf-controls, expression-blend

Is there a control in the Windows 8 Controls list that can be used to automatically show content both as a list view and as a thumbnail/tile view? I basically have a list of items that requires to be represented in this manner using XAML on a Windows 8 Store Application.

Comment: Is there a specific time you would want one over the other?

Comment: not sure if I understood your question. I have 2 buttons [1 to show the List View and the other 2 show the Thumbnail View]. I am not sure what is the control that I will need to use to perform this view mode. Is there an in built control that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you want to display information two different ways, you will have two separate views.  You will also have a property to which the visibility of your views are bound.  One view will show when the property is true and the other will show when your property is false.  When you press your button, then negate the value of your property (i.e. property  = !property).